# Error splicing file: Input/output error with a USB SD/HC card reader

Tags: usb, clipboard, sd-card

I recently got a new Droid Bionic, and it has the SD/HC card.

Today, I got a new USB card reader that reads the HC format. When I plug it into my Linux Mint 11 (katya), Gnome 32-bit computer, I get this error every I try to copy or move any file off of the card onto my desktop:

Error splicing file: Input/output error

I don't have the problem on a Windows Vista computer.  Any ideas???

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Connect your usb card reader with your memory card and give the output of these commands (execute in one line): `dmesg|tail -n 40; lsusb`